# After browsing binary tree appears something unuseful

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I created a binary tree.
As nods I gave the values:1,5,7,3,4,2.After adding the given nods and going through the tree in pre order, I get the result:1-5-3-2-4-7-33-.
I do not understand where this 33 comes from. Who knows, please help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct nod
{
    int inf;
    nod *st, *dr;
}ARB;
ARB *tns;
void add(ARB * &r,int info)
{
    if(!r)
    {
        r=new ARB;
        r->inf=info;
        r->st=r->dr=0;
    }
    else
        if(info<r->inf) add(r->st,info);
        else if(info>r->inf) add(r->dr,info);
             else cout<<"\n exist\n";
}
void create(ARB* &r)
{
    int info,n,i;
    cout<<"nr of nods";cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"nod: "<<i<<":";
        cin>>info;
        add(r,info);
    }
}
void rsd(ARB *r)
{
  if(r != NULL)
  {
    printf(" %d - ",r->inf);
    rsd(r->st);
    rsd(r->dr);
  }
}
int main()
{
    ARB *rad=0;
    int x;
    create(rad);
    add(rad,x);
    rsd(rad);

}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Why do you use tiny, non-descriptive variable names? People reading your code can't tell what the variables mean.

Comment: `x` is uninitialized in main. Is that your issue?

Comment: lakeweb - it needs when i make a call to add function

Comment: Your code is more or less fine (except for the cryptic identifiers and the poor indentation, but that doesn't prevent the program from being correct). The only problem I can see here is the `x` variable that is not initialized. Try `add(rad,1234);` instead of `add(rad,x);`

Comment: @Cristyan _" it needs when i make a call to add function"_ What??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer adds an extra node because you told it to:

```
ARB *rad=0;
int x;      // <-- unspecified value
create(rad);
add(rad,x); // <-- added to tree
rsd(rad);
```